# sequelize multiple association

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I want to associate 3 models namely Project, Contractor and Contract

```
const Project = sequelize.define('Project', {prjName: DataTypes.STRING})
const Contractor = sequelize.define('Contractor', {orgName: DataTypes.STRING})
const Contract = sequelize.define('Contract', {contractNum: DataTypes.STRING})
```

and the data for this project table will be 'prj1', 'prj2'
and the data for this contractor table will be 'EngConsultant'

contract has one-to-one association with contractor and ManyToMany association with projcet
i.e., Project can have many contracts and one contract may be assigned to more than one project.

Here in my above example 'EngConsultant' awarded a contract to look after 'prj1' and 'prj2'
since Project and Contract have manyToMany relation it will have a join table prj_contract

the data received for project will be prjname and for contractor orgName
the data received for contract will be

```
contractNum(string), orgId(number), prjId Array(number).
```

I am using sequelize:6.28.0 sequelize-cli:6.6.0.
My question is:

1. The contarctor may have more than one contract in a project. Do I have to associate?
2. how to remove cratedAt, updatedAt column in the join table.
3. how to add data to contract model
4. how to write the query to have from all the 3 table so that the output
   will be an array

```
[{prjId,prjname,orgid,orgName,contractid,contractNum}...]
```

Any advice, idea, link to a blog post, link to an article, etc. would be greatly appreciated

I have added individual table with data without any problem. I could not find any example to post an array of data to the join table.I could write a normal SQL query to get the output I wanted. Since I new to sequelize, I need some help

Comment: Two conflicting things: `contract has one-to-one association with contractor` and `The contarctor may have more than one contract in a project`. Care to clarify?

Comment: Thank you @Anatoly, In contract table, one contractor is assigned to one contract only. My question was while designing the system do we have to consider that the contractor may have more than one contract in a project